# How to use a structural directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to make a structural directive that will display the element depending on the width of the screen.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vim8-2-resize-template-pmp1b5?file=app/shared/if-viewport-size.directive.ts

My example work, but it skip at medium size. How to fix it?

Comment: You don't need a custom directive. You can just use `*ngIf` in the parent component, `<app-child-component *ngIf="some_boolean_in_the_.ts_file_attached_to_this_component">This component will only render if the condition is true</app-child-component>`

Comment: @JDunken Yes, I know this option, but according to my conditions I need it exactly as in the example.

Comment: Ricardo Ferreira, How to fix this condition?

Comment: You need to drop the `.ts` from this import `import {APP_CONFIG, AppConfig} from '../app.config.ts';` and write a reducer then.

Comment: JDunken, Please fork what you mean, I don’t understand.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are overwriting the `window.onresize` value.

I suggest using a `Subject` having the `onresize` value then subscribe to the subject in the different directive instances.

```
public windowResize$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(window.innerWidth);
window.onresize = event => {
     this.windowResize$.next(window.innerWidth);
};
```

[Running fork.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58134801)